# syntax error sql PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

```
$register = "INSERT INTO wcf1_user (username, regIP, password, salt, email)
                    VALUES('$username', '$ip', SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(CONCAT(salt, $pwd)))), '$llamada', '$email')";
```

Hola, estoy intentando realizar un mysqli_query en php y ejecutar este código de sql en PHP, pero tengo un error al llamar la variable $pdw, necesito la contraseña en ese método, ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Si `$pwd` es una cadena debería ir entrecomillada. Cuidado con el valor de `salt` si la contraseña depende él, la columna debería ir antes.

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar lo que intentas hacer aquí: `SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(CONCAT(salt, $pwd))))`? ¿Por qué dos `CONCAT`? Por otra parte, `SHA1` no se considera seguro hoy día. [Revisa las notas del MR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html): *"Se han dado a conocer exploits para los algoritmos MD5 y SHA-1. Es posible que desee considerar el uso de otra función de cifrado unidireccional descrita en esta sección, como SHA2()."* Desde PHP tú podrías trabajar con `password_hash` y `password_verify`. Además de esto, el código en sí mismo es vulnerable a *inyección SQL*.

Comment: @A.Cedano Estoy utilizando 2 concat por que así programé el registro de cuentas de esa manera dentro del servidor de juego, por otra parte, ¿Debería utilizar SHA2?

Comment: Si la seguridad te importa sí. [Lee el MR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha2): *"SHA2() puede considerarse criptográficamente más seguro que MD5() o SHA1().*", pero, hay condiciones: *"Esta función solo funciona si MySQL se ha configurado con soporte SSL"*.

Answer (score 0):

en php se concatena con PUNTO

```
$mivar1.$mivar2
```

o

```
$mivar1."un texto".$mivar2
```

o

```
$mivar1.'Otro Texto'.$mivar2
```

Comment: Intente utilizar esto y no funciona ```"INSERT INTO wcf1_user (username, regIP, password, salt, email)
                    VALUES('$username', '$ip', SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(CONCAT(salt, '.$pwd.')))), '$llamada', '$email')";```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un error en tu codigo, no puedes usar una funcion dentro de un string...

la forma correcta de tu sentencia es:

```
$register = "INSERT INTO wcf1_user (username, regIP, password, salt, email)
                VALUES('$username', '$ip', '".SHA1($llamada . SHA1($llamada . $pwd))."', '$llamada', '$email')";
```

Ademas por cuestiones de legibilidad y mantenimiento, es recomendable generar primero la contraseña encriptada y despues guardarla..

```
$psw = SHA1($llamada . SHA1($llamada . $pwd));
$register = "INSERT INTO wcf1_user (username, regIP, password, salt, email)
                    VALUES('$username', '$ip', '$psw', '$llamada', '$email')";
```

Comment: ahora me dice esto: ```Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function CONCAT() in```

Comment: tienes toda la razon @user264129, al moverlo olvide convertir la concatenacion, ya hice la correccion del codigo, espero esto resuelva tu problema... saludos